# Configure two DHCP relay agent in same Vlan

Tags: dhcp, dhcp-server

Based on a recent issue I encountered, I'm raising the question. Say you have a VLAN that spans between a few switches, but there are two VLAN IP interfaces at two different places in the same area, both with DHCP relay addresses configured for the same servers. Meaning both would receive a DHCP Discover message and conduct an IP directed broadcast. One offer for each subnet comes back from the servers. The computer receives both Offers. But my computer does not accepts any of the offers and it again send DHCP Discover packet. is there any criteria by which dhcp client decides whether to accept DHCP offer or not.